# Cloud download icon gray and cannot re-download purchased app

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Why can't I download this purchased app on iOS 12.3.1?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the link for the app?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be available at the moment in either your Store or anywhere at all.

You had downloaded it in the past, so it has the cloud and arrow but due to some reasons, the app is not on the App Store, thus the greyed out icon.